# Make embedded Youtube video thumbnail printable (@media print)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing, youtube

In my blog, I sometimes insert an embedded Youtube video using their "Share > Embed" code like this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sFrNsSnk8GM"
 frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; 
picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I'm currently editing the `@media print { }` style to make a compilation of the articles of my blog printable. It works for nearly everything except for these embdedded Youtube videos: in this case nothing at all is displayed.

It can easily be tested here: [Live demo](http://gget.it/obbk/test.html). Do "Print" in your browser, the Print Preview will show a blank image.

**Question: how to have a thumbnail (the same than the one we see on screen when the video is not playing yet) when printing a page from the browser?**

Tested with Chrome 69, Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many options, you can do it using js, css and html, which path you choose depends only on you. I will show you the simplest one with an additional html;)

```css
.youtube-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 560px;
  height: 315px;
}

.youtube-box img {
  display: none;
}

.youtube-box iframe {
  z-index: 1;
}

@media print {
  .youtube-thumbnail {
    display: block !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="youtube-box">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sFrNsSnk8GM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; 
      picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <img class="youtube-thumbnail" src="https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/sFrNsSnk8GM/0.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

I once made a script for lazy loading youtube [lazy-youtube](https://github.com/tomik23/lazy-youtube).

It consists in the fact that I only add such a div `<div class="ytLazy__item" data-yt-type="5" data-yt-id="BsTKKhU_Mq8"></div>`
I download the thumbnail and only clicking the play icon loads all the scripts from yotube. This is much better than packing iframe right away :)

This script could be extended to include this thumbnail when printing.

**SECOND EXAMPLE**

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const iframeElement = document.querySelectorAll('.youtube-iframe');
  iframeElement.forEach(iframe => {
    const idYoutube = iframe.getAttribute('src').split('/').pop();
    const imgElement = document.createElement('img');
    imgElement.src = `https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/${idYoutube}/0.jpg`;
    imgElement.className = 'youtube-thumbnail';
    iframe.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', imgElement);
  });
});
```

```css
.youtube-box {
  position: relative;
}

.youtube-box img {
  display: none;
}

.youtube-box iframe {
  z-index: 1;
}

.youtube-iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
}

.embed-responsive-16by9::before {
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}

.embed-responsive::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
}

@media print {
  .youtube-thumbnail {
    display: block !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="youtube-box embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="youtube-iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sFrNsSnk8GM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What did you remove the code snippet, it was helpful ;) Could you insert it again?

Comment: I did not delete but hid under the link, now it should be visible.

Comment: Strangely, I used your code (and nothing else) to create this http://gget.it/tiek/test.html but when doing "print" with Chrome on this page, it's still blank... Do you see the same thing?

Comment: You used my example wrongly. Copy what is visible above. The css code and html whole.

Comment: I posted [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58087248), by reusing your idea. Do you see a **more general way than having to add an `<img ... >`** (manually or automatically with JS), that would work also for Spotify embedded players (try to "Print" this page: https://newsroom.spotify.com/2018-09-04/how-to-embed-spotifys-play-button/ you'll see the same problem), Soundcloud players, etc. ?

Comment: I added a second solution width js. As for spotify, I will see tomorrow how this could be solved. It's best to post the next thread related to this problem, let's not mess up here.

Comment: Nice solution with JS! Last thing, do you think we can remove `width: 560px;
  height: 315px;` hardcoded, and let JS find it itself?

Comment: I made an update of the second example. I removed width and height from the iframe. I added two classes from [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/embed/) to properly display and scale iframe, it is now responsive ```.embed-responsive .embed-responsive-16by9```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the accepted answer's idea, here is another way to do it:

```css
.youtube-thumbnail { display: none; }
@media print {
.youtube { display: none !important; }
.youtube-thumbnail { display: block !important; }
}
```

```html
<iframe class="youtube" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sFrNsSnk8GM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<img class="youtube-thumbnail" src="https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/sFrNsSnk8GM/0.jpg" alt="">
```