# Displaying a video as a thumbnail using HTML and print preview

Tags: html, video, thumbnails, mp4, print-preview

After doing some [research](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20075875/2287576) I found that it was possible to show a MP4 video as a thumbnail using HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <video width="400" controls="controls" preload="metadata">
        <source src="file:///C:/video.mp4#t=0.5" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

The problem is that when I try to print preview, the thumbnail is blank. See:

[image]

Is it not possible to display a video as a thumbnail and it be visible in print preview? Note that my intention is to not have a video player as such, all I am trying to do is show the video as a thumbnail.

Comment: Might want to look at the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58084276/make-embedded-youtube-video-thumbnail-printable-media-print

Comment: @OmarSiddiqui Thanks for the link. I had a look at the answers there, but they imply that there is also an actual thumbnail image file. In my case I just have a video. Since I would have to manually prepare a thumbnail I just as well just treat it as an image, and I already support images in my application.